# Must the entropy change produced within a system always be greater than 0?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

In McQuarrie's Physical Chemistry text the following is claimed in regard to a system's change in entropy:

> $$dS=dS_{exch}+dS_{prod}$$

That is, the system's change in entropy can be separated into a contribution from heat exchange with the surroundings, as well as a contribution from changes to the components of the system.

It seems natural to interpret  $dS_{exch}$ as the change in entropy due to changes in the system's translational degrees of freedom, and $dS_{prod}$ as the change in entropy due to changes in the system's spatial degrees of freedom. Is this interpretation misleading?

McQuarrie then goes on to claim:

> For an irreversible or spontaneous process, $dS_{prod}$ > 0

This is where I'm having trouble. It seems that for an extremely slow irreversible isothermal process where $dS_{exch}$=-$dS_{surr}$, it will always be the case that $dS_{prod}$>0. However, I question that $dS_{prod}$>0 for all irreversible processes. What about an endothermic reaction of the form:

$$
A + B \rightarrow C
$$

It seems that such a reaction could have $dS_{prod}<0$, provided that $T_{surr}>T_{sys}$ such that $| q_{sys}/T_{sys} | > | q_{surr}/T_{surr} |$ and $dS_{univ}=dS_{prod}+dS_{exch}+dS_{surr}$ > 0.

Comment: Your interpretations of the exchange and production are not correct.  For a reversible process, production is zero and for an irreversible process, production is only positive.  The entropy production in an irreversible process is due to viscous dissipation, finite heat conduction, molecular diffusion, and chemical reaction with finite reaction rate (driving force).  This has nothing to do with the surroundings.

Comment: But a chemical reaction which reduces the number of spatial degrees of freedom within the system would contribute negatively to the system's entropy production, correct? In that case it seems that the other factors contributing to the entropy production would have to sum to a positive contribution which outweighs this negative contribution.

Comment: A chemical reaction proceeding at finite reaction rate generates entropy.

Comment: I guess I'm overly focused on a reaction where two atoms combine to form a diatomic molecule. It seems there is more uncertainty about the positional microstate of the reactants, although I guess I'm not accounting for vibrational degrees of freedom that the products gain.

Comment: I'm just going to accept as a postulate that $dS_{prod}>0$ for any irreversible process. I certainly accept that this is the case for isolated systems, and I guess I can consider any arbitrary closed system to be an isolated system which exchanges heat.